Web MediaRecorder API equivalent in React Native
I need media recorder audio type stream in react native application for real time voice processing.
Which does not seems to be working. Is there any node package which does the same or any other alternative I can use ?
const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });

